# LOAD DATA INFILE inserts question mark in front of first record

Tags: mysql

I'm getting frustrated trying to load data from a .txt file into a mysql table using LOAD DATA INFILE. The text file is a list of countries and their respective capital cities.

Here's the query I'm using:

```
$sql = "LOAD DATA local INFILE 'D:/wamp64/www/mySRS/data.txt'
        INTO TABLE example CHARACTER SET UTF8 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\\r\\n' (country, capital)";
```

The data loads fine except for one thing, there is always a question mark placed at the start of the first record. So the first record looks like this:

1 ?Afghanistan Kabul

The text file looks like this:

```
Afghanistan | Kabul
Albania | Tirana
Algeria | Algiers
Andorra | Andorra la Vella
Angola | Luanda
```

etc...

It's saved in UTF-8 format

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show us the first two lines of `data.txt` ?

Comment: Does the `data.txt` contain lines as follows: `1|"Afganistan Kabul`?

Comment: all lines should look the same

Comment: Here's what the file looks like:

Comment: Afghanistan | Kabul
Albania | Tirana
Algeria | Algiers
Andorra | Andorra la Vella